# How to set a dojo combobox store

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis

I'm working on a web application and am attempting to set combo boxes based off of a query built into an ArcGIS map service.  I set the first combo box based off of a query and when I select a value from that I want to query an ArcGIS map service to fill the second.

For testing purposes I default the first combo box value to an option and the query works to fill the second combo box.  However when I change the first combo box I get an error with setting the store for the second combo box.

Please forgive the ugliness of the code.  I'm making it "work" right now and will clean it up when I learn a bit more.

```
function startCat(results) {

        var items=[];
        var features = results.features;
        features.forEach(function(feature) {
            cat = feature.attributes.CATEGORY;
            items.push({name:cat});
        });

        var data = {
            label: 'name',
            items: items
        };
        var store = new ItemFileReadStore({data:data});

        // create combobox
        var comboBox = new ComboBox({
            id: "catSelect",
            name: "Category",
            value: "LCC",
            store: store,
            onChange: changeCat,
        }, "catSelect").startup();

    // SUBCategory combo box fill with query
        var subcatqueryTask = new QueryTask("http://sroarcgis.ducks.org/ducksunlimited/rest/services/WSITable/MapServer/4");
        var subcatquery = new Query();
        subcatquery.returnGeometry = false;
        subcatquery.outFields = ["SUBCATEGORY"];
        subcatquery.where = "CATEGORY = '" + dom.byId("catSelect").value + "'";
        subcatqueryTask.execute(subcatquery, startSubCat);

    }

function changeCat(){
// SUBCategory combo box fill with query
    var subcatqueryTask = new QueryTask("http://sroarcgis.ducks.org/ducksunlimited/rest/services/WSITable/MapServer/4");
    var subcatquery = new Query();
    subcatquery.returnGeometry = false;
    subcatquery.outFields = ["SUBCATEGORY"];
    subcatquery.where = "CATEGORY = '" + dom.byId("catSelect").value + "'";
    //domConstruct.destroy("subcatSelect");
    subcatqueryTask.execute(subcatquery, startSubCat);
}

function changeSubCat(results) {

    var items=[];
    var features = results.features;
    features.forEach(function(feature) {
        cat = feature.attributes.SUBCATEGORY;
        items.push({name:cat});
    });

    var data = {
        label: 'name',
        items: items
    };
    var store = new ItemFileReadStore({data:data});

    var comboBox = dom.byId("subcatSelect");
    comboBox.setStore(store);
}
```

I am creating the second combo box in the startCat function for testing purposes.  I would like to have it elsewhere.

I attempted to create the category combo box declaratively at first but again I couldn't set the store unless I did it when creating the box.

As you will see in the code I tried destroying the second combo box and recreating it but I always received the error that subcatSelect is already registered.

What is the best way to do this?  Is there a proper setStore method that I haven't found or is destroying and recreating the combo box a better way to do this?  If it is a better way how can I destroy it?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to answer my own question but after two days of playing around with this and writing the question I figured it out just a short while later.

I changed one of the functions to set the store.  I had to use dom.registry and setAttribute

```
function changeSubCat(results) {

    var items=[];
    var features = results.features;
    features.forEach(function(feature) {
        cat = feature.attributes.SUBCATEGORY;
        items.push({name:cat});
    });

    var data = {
        label: 'name',
        items: items
    };
    var store = new ItemFileReadStore({data:data});

    node = registry.byId("subcatSelect");
    node.setAttribute("store", store);
}
```

Comment: node.setAttribute is deprecated
https://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dijit_form_ComboBox_setAttribute

use node.set instead
https://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dijit_form_ComboBox_set